# Automatic margins when making a PDF in Pandoc?

Tags: pdf, pandoc, margins

Is there some way to, instead of specifying `--variable papersize="A4" --variable margin-left="1.2in" --variable margin-top="1.2in"` for the command, and having to change the two last ones every time you change the font, I can set the margins to "automatic" somehow? So that the content pages are always placed evenly in the middle horizontally and vertically for each PDF page?

Note: It must be on the command line; not some weird separate config file.

Comment: Why do you keep creating new user IDs to ask the same questions over and over when they are not answered?

Comment: @DavidPostill, please add dup reference, so I can vote to close. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

A review of the [documentation for Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) finds no way.